# Javascript match doesn't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and am trying to extract a substring using Regex. Here is an example:

```
var mainString = "SNOW ",  
stringToMatch = 'snow',  
regExp = new RegExp(stringToMatch + '[,\\s][^a-zA-Z]','ig');  
var match = mainString.match(regExp);
```

`console.log(match)` gives me a `null`.

I tried the same regex in the regexr.com editor and it matches there. I don't see where I am going wrong. Can someone please help me find the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your regex construction:

```
regExp = new RegExp(stringToMatch + '[,\\s][^a-zA-Z]','ig');
```

`[^a-zA-Z]` matches any *character* that is not in the set `[a-zA-Z]`.<sup>*</sup> It does not match the end of a string, which is not a character and would be indicated by `$`. So, your regex would match `"sNoW ,"`, `"sNoW 1"`, or `"SNOW,#"` (for examples), but not `"Snow,"` or `"Snow "`.

You probably want:

```
// match a non-alphabetic character or the end of the string
regExp = new RegExp(stringToMatch + '[,\\s](?:[^a-z]|$)','ig');

// or

// simply match the word and then stop at a word boundary, \b
regExp = new RegExp(stringToMatch + '\\b','ig');
```

* Note that `[a-zA-Z]` is redundant with the `i` flag; just use `[a-z]`.

Comment: This worked, thank you Ed! I didn't understand the part 'It does not match the end of a string, which is not a character and would be indicated by $' If you don't mind, will you please explain it?

Comment: @Ritu Glad to help! What I meant was that `[^a-zA-Z]` matches only actual characters, such as `2`, `#`, or `>`. It doesn't match the end of the string itself. In other words, imagine this regex `/.[^a-z]/gi` and this text `a@b@c`. In that case `a@` and `b@` would be matches. `c` would not match, because there is nothing after `c` that matches `[^a-z]`. To allow the end of the string to match, you would use `$`, like this: `/.([^a-z]|$)/gi`. Then, any character followed by either (1) a non-alphabetic character or (2) the end of the string matches. So, `a@`, `b@`, and `c` would be your matches.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the correct result. *SNOW* is not in the result because there is nothing after the space so

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

does not matches nothing

Comment: I've edited my input. Will you please check now and let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: The problem is the same there is nothing to match after the space, so [^a-zA-Z] does matches nothing. If your input was "SNOW -" it will match